# SQL Generate Column name in WHILE or FOR NEXT loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am selecting distinct values from 20 columns in a query as below, and wondered if it would be possible to do this in a neater way by using a loop?  Having read some of the answers on here for similar topics, it appears that the general consensus is, Dynamic SQL is to be avoided?

In my case, I am simply looking to have a hard coded "Defect" and concatenate an integer variable to the end for each loop i.e. 1,2,3,4 .... 20.  Is this somehow possible?  My current query looks like this, and it doesn't look pretty!

```
SELECT Defect1 AS HashKeys FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect2 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect3 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect4 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect5 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect6 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect7 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect8 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect9 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect10 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect11 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect12 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect13 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect14 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect15 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect16 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect17 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect18 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect19 FROM VisionMachineResults
UNION
SELECT Defect20 FROM VisionMachineResults
```

Comment: Each row in this table represents an automatically inspected part.  The defects are HASH keys, that were generated in the inspection software and automatically written to a database.  Up to 20 defects per part can be recorded.  I think you perhaps misunderstand the intention of the table

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not something you should avoid - it is just a tool like everything else. To use it properly one must have a certain level of skill  - which, unfortunately, many do not have. You should be less concerned about "neater" or "pretty" when writing code and more concerned about correctness and efficiency. Here, your task is made more tedious and difficult because of your broken schema. Given this is likely a one-time thing (which you can encapsulate in a view or in a saved code snippet), there isn't much to be gained by alternatives.

Comment: And any time you use UNION, you need to carefully consider whether to use `UNION` vs. `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using `UNPIVOT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [value]
FROM VisionMachineResults
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [column] IN ([Defect1], [Defect2], ... [Defectn])
) UNPVT;
```

Comment: Thinking about this further, is there a simple way to count the occurrences within the same query?

Comment: For example, `[value], COUNT([value])` and after the `UNPVT` add `GROUP BY [value]`